# ¿Cómo puedo obtener las palabras más repetidas en una tabla?

Tags: php, sql

En una base de datos tengo una tabla donde almaceno frases y quiero obtener cuáles son las palabras que más se repiten, con una consulta SQL y filtrar con PHP el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco no es posible hacerlo solamente con SQL (porfavor corrijanme si estoy equivocado).

Pero podes facilmente traer todas tus frases y filtrarlas.

Imaginemos que traes tus frases y las guardas en un array

```
$frases = ["hola soy luis","alo soy luis","mañana es lunes"];
```

Podemos crear un array de palabras. Esto lo hacemos uniendo todas las frases en un solo string y despues separando las palabras.

```
$frases = implode(" ",$frases);
$frases = explode(" ",$frases);
$frases = array_count_values($frases);
```

Usando la funcion array_count_values($yElArrayDePalabras) te contara cada vez que se repite una palabra

Resultado

```
array(7) { ["hola"]=> int(1) ["soy"]=> int(2) ["luis"]=> int(2) ["alo"]=> int(1) ["mañana"]=> int(1) ["es"]=> int(1) ["lunes"]=> int(1) }
```

Esto es suponiendo que tus datos de entrada estan "limpios" si en tus frases hay puntos, comas, mayusculas o simbolos habra que aplicar los respectivos filtros

Ej: Si queremos limpiar las mayusculas usaremos

```
$frases = implode(" ",$frases);
$frases = strtolower($frases);
$frases = explode(" ",$frases);
$frases = array_count_values($frases);
```

Siempre es mas facil limpiarlo cuando los datos son un string (Despues del implode pero antes del explode).